# What is wrong with this stored procedure ? It doesn't work properly

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures

```
Create Or Replace Procedure ASS1_RESET_TABLES IS
Begin
    Delete * From PAYDETAILS;

    Delete * From EMPLOYEE;

    Insert into EMPLOYEE(EmpId, EmpNumber, EmpSurname, EmpFirstname, Gender, HourlyRate)
    Values(ASS1_EMP_SEQ.nextval, 2, 'Pritchett', 'Jay', 'M', 12.50);

    Commit;
  End;
```

Comment: What is the error you are getting? how do you mean it doesn't work properly?

Comment: Error(3,2): PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored

Comment: this is one error that i get

Comment: Error(3,9): PL/SQL: ORA-00903: invalid table name this is another one

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try:

```
Create Or Replace Procedure ASS1_RESET_TABLES 
as
Begin

  Delete From PAYDETAILS;
  Delete From EMPLOYEE;

  Insert into EMPLOYEE(EmpId,EmpNumber,EmpSurname,EmpFirstname,Gender,HourlyRate)
  Values(ASS1_EMP_SEQ.nextval,2,'Pritchett','Jay','M',12.50);

  Commit;

End;
```

Changes made:
`Delete * From PAYDETAILS;` should be `Delete From PAYDETAILS;`
`IS` replaced with `AS`

Comment: Any details on **what** you've changed? (it's always a good idea to explain not just to feed an OP with fish)

Comment: `Delete *`  to `Delete`

Comment: @zerkms he replaced 'is' with 'as', removed * from delete statements.

Comment: @andrew-buchan: I personally actually don't care of actual changes, my advice was to put it to the answer so that OP could learn from it.

Comment: Well they are here now, so no need to fret.

Comment: Thanks @zerkms for pointing out the issues, will do the same for the next answer onwards.

Comment: `IS` and `AS` are interchangeable here, as the [syntax diagram in the docs shows](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/create_procedure.htm). Very minor point, I know...